# Why isn't np.nan_to_num() converting this (n x m) array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion, nan

I would like to set all `nan` entries in my numpy array `a` to zero.

Regardless how I use `np.nan_to_num()`, the array is not processed at all (it still leaves `np.nan` in the array)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.empty((0, 3), dtype='object')
for runner in range(10):
    a = np.insert(a, a.shape[0], [[1, np.nan, 1]], axis=0)
```

These are are my unsuccessful tries:

```
np.nan_to_num(a)
np.nan_to_num(a,copy=True)
np.nan_to_num(a,copy=False)
a=np.nan_to_num(a)
a=np.nan_to_num(a,copy=False)
a=np.nan_to_num(a,copy=True)
```

Comment: `a = np.empty((0, 3), dtype='object')`  Why are you creating an `object` array?  `nan_to_num` will not replace `nan`s in `object` arrays.  Use a regular array of floating point values.

Answer (score 3):

As the `nan_to_num` docstring states:

> If `x` is not inexact, then no replacements are made.

And dtype object does not count as inexact.

If for some reason one needs to use dtype object (perhaps one wants to have `nan`s and exact `int`s, for example), then here is a work-around:

```
a[a!=a] = 0
```

Note that in theory there could be other objects than `nan` for which `x!=x` evaluates to True (one can of course create one's own class and fiddle with `__eq__`, `__neq__`) but in practice I can't think of any.

Only mildly contrived example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (6,)).astype(object)
>>> a[a%2==0] = np.nan
>>> 
>>> fact_exact = np.vectorize(math.factorial, 'O', 'O')
>>> 
>>> fact_exact(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 1972, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2048, in _vectorize_call
    outputs = ufunc(*inputs)
ValueError: factorial() only accepts integral values
>>> 
>>> a[a!=a] = 0
>>> fact_exact(a)
array([9819935662418089743352075922310862095706065486822583658822975979153852871637910339598847876493575760863201233608970580391009961465728060140206398380369810186460532083760537973722230477712617437079362600099095591538946730193485520929914465963675497331037894791629662134417383906616748712477435411911352595846133057242505006764835196420336585309344206359125847804414531691517822911373600118902137858177047463867389635205323328678714656377591230065986360526515442653777496908763065282294664208227077490200850296013058820462199153017425546879776071769432946284989651969735166129654123362278827485074178681546981559466233191972688158356430976918192398846419304865350500808417927115875428971873067092978672051108353026958311731456630717915806992149025378731927814021805881859364498816522297657223802150320368577537638698692463078070519911729996949263069045872688620575874758242248117345983373644762881336075203583068807371386560008413979828440302163961903567206206098114957943899603695885783671168564745354608640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
       22328783881661914958481873975346502495151470121092663127656427617172486869336444341196216861471796204456103981797935323465763492125980526669772652700063306391000092324747490987759008282321662774044560021923711172537165034028116470777032463317525690139861312277154265627409161865934581816407380706408159413469087649804140238680046340298380454769197056000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
       1,
       61249584099358401539774988285121649211647782880181065019552657036267338153088195303988201779967275642784589505913349592976251572958797164520286603082616258499126414850388770750032832244874744865500684599339365169094265281656246018624169125087086336929008659140773790287427038315506740711640971717627407262119806133914039569804387544893605360482632749642132398074143010093832414811273406748220437584361624445361171146706501836044960640727879585735220969146850637281930634576684379022439144569827759897323120413808197447743317836963898751450642251281351982277623696403714801809091137618510094637754741546381374172490209156669750628265287758243565040756752491082629092890931663069084118249960190350279925210044221389170848672643624902424798289485981643559009642358060100976306359010066013465973059932028926310180595315985960099791957394179039519432507444190747654625992620055591848528852607925564873303749001475451862943569149219508203963665660697011849205174996326078837279628237406181221912723812127044670946612175065696608648876366755523800502033220426264259724448110042998615347327090687044945724644868095726898042638404229137017574884525227292991943592508583104116919096883640157188742952660337139750108570879849335960456768856494175006057451288109527150100807278246132549650716938934121106772599000305859091685578549764454500874996178837114679306052077693402114826710945748516120895211107804543955416170463298478450007640457295281818515443548160000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
       1, 1], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue of how you are declaring your array.

```
a = np.array([[1,np.nan,3],[np.nan, 0, np.nan]])
a=np.insert(a, a.shape[0],[[1, np.nan, 1]], axis=0)

a
array([[ 1., nan,  3.],
   [nan,  0., nan],
   [ 1., nan,  1.]])

np.nan_to_num(a)
array([[1., 0., 3.],
   [0., 0., 0.],
   [1., 0., 1.]])
```